# Memory leaks in Android handler

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, bluetooth

I am trying to read data from a serial bluetooth stream in my android application. The data is send to a handler to display it. It works fine for a few minutes and then it stops showing data (The app keeps running however). I think it has to do with memory leaks in my handler but I don't know how to solve it..

[This is where I found the code](http://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/ece480/capstone/spring14/group01/docs/appnote/Wirsing-SendingAndReceivingDataViaBluetoothWithAnAndroidDevice.pdf)

I will be so happy if someone can help me.
Thanks in advance

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    static BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    static Handler mHandler = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Does the device support bluetooth?
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Device does not support Bluetooth",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        //Turn on Bluetooth if disabled
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
        }

        //Get the Bluetooth module device
        BluetoothDevice mDevice = null;
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                if(device.getName().equals("HC-06")) {
                    mDevice = device;
                }
            }
        }
        if(mDevice == null){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Device not found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"connected to " + mDevice.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            ConnectThread mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(mDevice);
            mConnectThread.start();

            mHandler = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    int begin = (int)msg.arg1;
                    int end = (int)msg.arg2;
                    switch(msg.what) {
                        case 1:
                            String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                            writeMessage = writeMessage.substring(begin, end);

                            ScrollView scrollView1 = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
                            TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusText);
                            textView1.append(writeMessage + "\n");
                            scrollView1.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

                            break;
                    }
                }
            };
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post logs? To determine if its a Memory leak - look at your logs, and filter on GC_ this will have number that goes up and down. If the number that follows GC_  continues going up the in your logs - you have a memory leak, if it goes up/down, then there's no memory leak and your problem lies elsewhere!

Comment: All my logs look like this with slightly different numbers
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 824K, 25% free 5400K/7172K, paused 4ms, total 4ms

Comment: OK so you're using 5.4k/7.7k memory- what you want to monitor is does 5.4k continue going up, or does it come down (this happens when garbage collection occurs) - If does come down from time to time, then your problem isn't a memory leak - can you post your crash logs, that may help to diagnose the issue?

Comment: 05-08 14:29:29.170: E/dalvikvm(2403): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4738K, 40% free 8376K/13955K, paused 13ms+25ms, total 107ms

05-08 14:29:29.900: E/dalvikvm(2403): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1676K, 41% free 8342K/13955K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 68ms

05-08 14:29:30.640: E/dalvikvm(2403): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1649K, 41% free 8319K/13955K, paused 12ms+12ms, total 68ms

05-08 14:29:31.370: E/dalvikvm(2403): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1632K, 41% free 8317K/13955K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 70ms

Comment: @Max Helskens
How much data do you pass?
Try my answer below

Answer (score 1):

It's not memory leaks,
in handleMessage() you should perform lightweight operations like setting text to textview.

BUT declare your scrollView1 and textview 1 as global params, just to avoit operation findViewById each time, it should help.

Also you passing some data but after generating string you crop it, so you don't need full data, isn't it better to perform that in you CommnadThread and pass exactly data what you need to show.

Comment: I discovered it has something to do with the buffer in the connected thread.
When I halve the size of the buffer the app stops twice as fast..

Comment: @Max Helskens
Sorry what means when you have size of the buffer?
As I see in that pdf size always 1024.

Comment: Yes, but when I made it smaller in the code it stopped faster.
So I think there's something wrong there..

Comment: @Max Helskens(it just make a lot of ui updates to fast )
when you make it smaller it started to make more frequent updates, 
so try to increase it for example 4096.


You should try to pass bigger chunks of data and do less frequent updates seems it calls really a lot of ui updates

Do you really need such amount of updates

Comment: We have a sensor that is continuously sensing and sending strings.
The app needs to react on this data so it needs to sense constantly

Comment: can you post code of that MainActivity(activity_main) layout, maybe it's complex

Comment: If you use AndroiStudio there on bottom right corner you have tab Memory Monitor check their how much memory your app uses

Comment: The layout is really simple, its just a scrollview and a textview.
this was supposed to be some kind of bluetooth terminal. Later I want to implement that it reacts when the received data is equal to something else.

Comment: what device do you use for test? and let me know your app memory usage

Comment: tablet is a samsung galaxy
and the usage is about 75%

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, it works when I replace the run method in ConnectedThread with this:

```
public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int begin = 0;
        int byteOffset = 0;
        int byteCount;
        while (true) {
            try {
                byteCount = buffer.length - byteOffset;
                byteOffset += mmInStream.read(buffer, byteOffset, byteCount);
                for(int i = begin; i < byteOffset; i++) {
                    if(buffer[i] == "#".getBytes()[0]) {
                        mHandler.obtainMessage(1, begin, i, buffer).sendToTarget();
                        begin = i + 1;
                        if(i == byteOffset - 1) {   
                            byteOffset = 0;
                            begin = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                    }                       
                }
                if(byteOffset == 1024){
                    begin = 0;
                    byteOffset = 0;
                }                   
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```